# How to write cron job for laravel(5.2) project in centOs server?

Tags: cron, laravel-5.3, centos7

I have a laravel 5.3 project sets up at CentOS 7 server. Now I want to run a cron job in that server. So I write the command like
2 * * * * /usr/local/bin/php http://projectname/methodName
which didn't work actually. Can anyone specify the way to write it in a right command? Should I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

**First** of all the path that need to b set in crontab is not your http path, it is absolute path.

`* * * * * php /var/www/html/rummykhan.com/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`

**Second**, you just need to run

`php artisan make:command TestCommand`

and it will create a Command Class in `app/Console/Commands` directory of your project, Now you can write your cron job code in this file.

**Last**, Now you need to register this command to Laravel Console Kernel, which is `app/Console/Kernel.php` commands array.

```
/**
 * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $commands = [
    TestCommand::class,
];
```

That's it.